# How to enable unlimited fine-grained ABAC in AWS for S3 objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, abac

I didn't find any way how to enable Attribute Based Access Control for S3 objects if I need to assign more tag values than one S3 Tag can support:

> ... tag values can be up to 256 Unicode characters in length. [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-tagging.html)

For example, if I need very fine-grained ABAC to mark an S3 object with 1000 IDs in the Tag Value of the Tag Key `IDs`, then I will overreach the maximum 256 characters, e.g. `IDs`=`1,2,3,4...999,1000`

What can be a solution of that problem?

Comment: Why would you think such a thing is supported?

Comment: @Marcin because such things might be requested from a business to support a variety of deep level ABAC, e.g. if they use some attributes with a plenty of values

Comment: Then please feel free to request such a thing from AWS. Hopefully they will implement it for you quickly.